# Different folder for views - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a reusable Dashboard for my apps, so I decided to put everything in a folder like `app/Dashboard`. I've managed to have routes, controller, middlewares, etc. But, now I'd like to have views also in that folder. I added the path in `config/view.php`, the problem with that is that if I have two views with the same name in `app/Dashboard/Views` and in the default `resources/views`, of course the view in the default path would be loaded.

Do you have a better idea? Can I do something like `return view('dashboard:login')` in my controller using only the Laravel standard tools?

Comment: Try to read about creating packages in laravel, as this is what you're doing right now. Section `Views` can explain something https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this part of the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#views. You are almost right, but you need to use two colons

```
return view('dashboard::login');
```

Comment: You're right. This looks cool, I'll try to do it like a package. Thanks!